# Isn't using God's name as stage name a blasphemy?

Tags: names, shemos-sacred-names, modern-times

I just came to know there's a singer named Elohim

Isn't having God's name as stage name a blasphemy?

Comment: As a side note, the word elohim has other meanings as well, so as an example, it might not be the best choice.

Comment: @rosend any set of letters/sounds can have multiple meanings as well. None ttbomk are inherently holy

Comment: @DoubleAA Let’s say that someone named themselves the Shem Havaya as it’s actually pronounced (not that we know what that is). Would you say that’s a better example?

Comment: @donielf no I would not. there's still a very high chance it means something else in some other language or context, and even if it doesn't currently it certainly could

Answer (score 2):

The name Elohim is not used uniquely for Gcd.

In the Bible it sometimes refers to *judges*. Other times - Bnei Elohim - it refers to *angels* or special people.

Seems like it's becoming a popular name, based on the [Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elohim_(disambiguation))

> Elohim may also refer to:
>
> - Elohim (gods), "Sons of El" in Canaanite mythology
> - Elohim (Alpha Blondy album)
> - Elohim (Aka Moon album)
> - Elohim, a species of extraterrestrials that created life on Earth in the UFO religion
>     Raëlism
> - The Elohim, a race of godlike beings in the fantasy series
> - The Chronicles of Thomas Covenant by Stephen R. Donaldson
> - Elohim, an indie pop musician
> - Brasheedah Elohim, American-Israeli women's professional basketball player
>
> See also
>
> - Elohim City,
>     Oklahoma, a private community in Adair County, Oklahoma

Point being that while it feels repulsive to use Gcd's name, in this case - Elohim -  it only sounds like Gcd's name.